# How can I make my count-group by query return the zero values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

Sorry for my English!

I have this Attribution table in my postgresql database:

Table Attribution:

```
Id  | name | date
1  | peter | 2018-02-20
2  | peter | 2018-02- 28
3  | peter | 2018-02-20
3  | John  | (empty)
4  | mike  | 2018-02-18
5  | mike  | 2018-02-19
6  | mike  | 2018-02-19
7  | mike  | 2018-02- 02
8  | jack  | (empty)
9  | jack  | (empty)
10 | jack |(empty)
```

I want my request to give me that:

Result:

```
Id | name | count(Id)
1 | peter | 2
2 | john  | 0
3 | Mike  | 3
4 | jack  | 0
```

Here is my query:

```
Select attribution.id, attribution.name, count(attribution.id)
From attribution
Where date< '2018-02-21'
And date> '2018-02-15'
Group by attribution.id, attribution.name
```

Unfortunately, this query does not return me zeros. It returns me :

```
Id | name  | count(Id)
1  | peter | 2
2  | Mike  | 3
```

So my question is:
How can I make my query return the zero values ?

Thank you for your suggestions ☺️

Answer (score 0):

You can add `or date is null` predicate and count date instead of id

```
Select attribution.id, attribution.name, count(attribution.date)
From attribution
Where (date < '2018-02-21'
       And date > '2018-02-15')
      or date is null
Group by attribution.id, attribution.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `where` condition to the `select`, so all names are present:

```
Select a.id, a.name, 
       sum(case when date < '2018-02-21' and date > '2018-02-15' then 1 else 0 end)
From attribution a
Group by a.id, a.name;
```

Or, in Postgres, more succinctly as:

```
Select a.id, a.name, 
       sum( (date < '2018-02-21' and date > '2018-02-15')::int )
From attribution a
Group by a.id, a.name;
```

And, if the sequential column is important:

```
Select row_number() over (order by a.id) as seqnum,
       a.id, a.name, 
       sum( (date < '2018-02-21' and date > '2018-02-15')::int )
From attribution a
Group by a.id, a.name;
```